# Call function on string length

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call a function when the length of a state string get to 10 but nothing happens at the length of 10 until I click an extra key. Seems like the last character is never evaluated in getting the length. I have this

```
 onChangeText={(val) => {
 setFormData((prevState) => ({
   ...prevState,
   account_number: val,
    }));
    getName() 
           }
              }
```

then in the getName function

```
 const getName = async () => {
       
      if (
        formData.account_number.length === 10 &&
        formData.account_number != "" 
      ) {
àwait //do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because setState is async. The new value only update when the component re-render. So you should pass `val` to `getName` like this:

```
onChangeText = (val) => {
  ...
  getName(val)
} 

const getName = async (val) => {
  if (val.length === 10 ) {
    // await 
  }
}
```